# Authentication and Authorization in Microservices

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, microservices

I've been reading a fair bit on Microservices recently, and especially around AuthN and AuthZ. For the most part, this all makes a lot of sense, and I can see how it all should work.

For what I'm playing with, I going with delegated authorization - so I'm to be passing tokens around from client to service, and then passing the same token on from service to service. I also have an endpoint on the OAuth2 Service that will accept a token and return the details of the token - the User ID, the Start and End of the validity period, the scopes that the token is valid for, etc.

The problem that I'm running into here is - in order to correctly issue a token, there needs to be some communication with the User Service to ensure that the User that the token is for is actually valid. And in order to verify a Token, there needs to be some communication with the User Service to ensure that the User is still valid. And yet, in order to safely communicate with the User Service to get details about a User, a Token is needed that gives permission for this access.

I assume there is some standard practice on how to solve this circular dependency between the OAuth2 and User Service, but I've not seen any mention of it at all. Is this a common problem? Or have I just missed something obvious?

(Note - for now I'm only implementing Client Credentials Grant and Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant, since I'm only playing around to see how it all works and they're easier to call with cURL. I don't know that this makes any difference though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a bit of a chicken and egg problem. Not sure how much control you have over the authorization server, but one way of solving this issue is to secure the call to the user info service using [client certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate).

Another is to combine the user info service and authorization server into one service and eliminate the need for the call all together.

Comment: It's a pet project so I've got complete control over it all. I'm just playing and learning really :) Combining the services together I'm loathe to do because they are different concerns, but the client certificate option could work, or some other way of indicating that it's an internal call. I'm assuming that this is a solved problem though - other people must have hit exactly the same thing - but I couldn't find anything about it...

Comment: If you control both sides, you can of course also have your authorization server generate a token for itself to call the user info service.

Comment: So - client calls oauth, oauth generates a short lived token and uses it to call the user service, user service then calls back to oauth to verify the token, oauth just implicitly trusts it and let's it go, then the user service carries on and does the work. I kinda like that. Still have some more fine grained authz issues but that's not too bad...

Comment: There's no need for the user service to call back the auth service. JWT tokens are digitally signed and can be verified without going back to the issuer.

Comment: Only if every service has a copy of the signing key though, or else any third party can generate a token that passes as valid.

Comment: No, digital signatures use asymmetric encryption. The auth server signs a token with its private key, the service accepting the token only needs to public key to verify the signature. The public key can be given to anyone as it only allows someone to verify the signature, not sign.

Comment: Ah fair enough. I thought they used symmetric for some reason. Serves me right for going by memory instead of just looking it up... :) There is still the fact that without calling the oauth service to verify the token you can't really invalidate them, but that's not a major issue in this case...

Comment: In fact, if I never use JWT tokens to the outside world, then I can always implicitly trust JWT tokens that are valid without needing to check. The tokens issued to the outside clients can be reference tokens instead that need to be verified, but doing so can issue a JWT token for the same session that counts as pre-verified. I like that...